# Fusing edit_object_path and new_object_path into one path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For editing and creating a new object I want to have only one single path (say */admin/edit). As `new_object_path` and `edit_object_path` render the same _form.html.erb page is it possible    to fuse edit and new?
I hope it becomes clear what my question is about..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why do you want to do that?

Read about REST-architecture. `new` and `edit` actions have the different meanings. Yes, they use the same partial view (_form), but they have a different logic at the controller side. In the new action you create a very new (in most cases almost empty) object, but before  rendering edit action view you need to fetch object from database by the given (in the URL) object's ID.

I can't realise why you need to fuse two different by meanings (and by logic) actions?

You should use different views for `new` and `edit` actions and render partial view (_form) inside them (probably you've already seen such kind of views in automatically generated scaffolds).